# PHP-Files magically serverd with a leading TAB

Tags: php, apache, header, debian, mime-types

I got a weired behavior on my apache, php setup on debian system.

I tried to create an image with php and output it directly. It failed  permanent and the browser said sth. like corrupt image file. After a lot of try and error arroun 3 hours I figured out that there is a TAB character added right at the beginning ob my image content, that does not belong there.

To proove that its part of the apache-php setup I created a test.php file, that just contains the letter 'a' and coppied this file to test.html. So Both files just contain the letter a.
You can see the resulting tab here:

http://www.activeroom.net/test.php

http://www.activeroom.net/test.html

and even on the base url itself - its a php-file, too. 
Hope anybody can point me in the correct direction. Btw. on the console everything is fine: php test.php just returns an a. Maybe it is something about the Apache MimeTypes or headers?!

Comment: Welcome to SO, however, your question does not seem to involve _programming_. You might be better off asking this question on sister-site [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com). You can use your StackExchange-account there as well.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. Posted it again at ServerVault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How stupid - there was a php-file prepended through the php.ini. That file had a tab at the end. Sometimes things are really messed up.